# Issues getting an image texture to print on a Statasys J750

Tags: blender, color, polyjet-printer, grabcad-print, statasys-j750

I'm trying to print out a digital elevation model of a landscape with a satellite image of the landscape overlayed on it as a texture. I've been working with the makerspace at my University, who have a Statasys J750 polyjet 3D printer. However, my file prints without the texture, just as a totally black model. The folks at the makerspace have been helpful, but they aren't really sure what the issue is.

Here's my workflow:

1. Import my STL file for the DEM into Blender
2. Reduce the poly count of the model by dissolving all coplanar surfaces
3. Create materials for the base and for the terrain. For the base, assign a solid color (brown). For the terrain, assign a .png texture of a satellite image of the terrain, and project it onto the terrain from above using a UV mapping
4. Bake on the textures using "combined" bake type, with "direct," "indirect," and "diffuse" lighting and contributions (I'm not sure why this is necessary, but the makerspace staff told me that it is).
5. Export the project to a .obj file, selecting the "UV Coordinates," "Normals," "Colors," and "Triangulated Mesh" options.
6. Import the resulting .OBJ/.MTL/.PNG files into GrabCAD and print.

When viewing the model in GrabCAD, my model displays properly, with the .png texture displaying properly on the model, similarly to the screenshot from blender I included below. Even then, my model ends up printing without any color; just as a black piece of plastic. When printing other people's projects using the same settings in GrabCAD, things seem to work fine. The staff at the makerspace aren't really sure what the issue is, and say it is likely an issue with my model.

Is anyone willing to help me troubleshoot this issue? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of model in blender]